# Lua include external resource like: mysql = require "http://myServer.com/luasql.mysql"

Tags: mysql, lua

Is there a way to use something like this in **LUA**

```
mysql = require "http://myServer.com/luasql.mysql"
```

to get the same result as using

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
```

I can't access the webserver, just run lua scripts on it so is this possible in any kind of way?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to explain the situation

When you use

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
```

It referering a Driver that allow the connection, It does not have the information of your remote server.

In case your mysql database is remote, you can add host as another optional parameter to connect. Port can follow host as well:

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
local env  = mysql.mysql()
local conn = env:connect('test','root','123456','myserver.com','port')
```

`luasql.mysql` Is only a type of class

Comment: I think I don't get it at all. I have a Webserver, a closed system where i can run lua scripts and I got a mySQL Database which allows external requests. The Webserver (Apache in this case) does allow Cross Origins.

Comment: Sorry I edited the my answer
I think you can not access your database because your server does not allow Remote Connections, you should verify that your web server is enabled with it.

If you have it enabled for remote connections you should use the IP address instead of the domain

Comment: hrm u know how i can check it easily? I got an htaccess file containing Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"  inside the folders

Comment: I reviewed and Updated my answer, Basically you don't need to change `luasql.mysql` due to is a driver file. Your sever name will be established in `con` var

Comment: I got a problem than. Because the driver is not included in the system. I get "[DEBUG] 23:56:48: line 9: attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)" in the "mysql = require... " line and I got no access to install this driver. But Thank you a lot ;)

Comment: I will be grateful if you vote for my new answer, Thank You :)

Comment: of course i did but it isn't counted as long as i dont reach lvl 15 or smth i will come back when i am able to vote ;)